# MYSQL Join Two tables with same data

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

I have two tables `member` and `alumni`. `alumni` table can have the same `member` in more than one row with a different `year` field. I want to select all the data from both the table.
The table given is:

Alumni:

```
 id, regd, name,   status,    year

 1    1    kim     inactive   2013
 2    1    kim     inactive   2014
 3    1    kim     inactive   2015 //This is generated for alumni purpose
```

The table member given is:

```
regd, name,   status,    year
 1    kim     Active     2015
```

The expected output is:

```
`regd`, `name,`   `status,`    `year`
 1       kim       Active       2015 
 1       kim       inactive     2014 
 1       kim       inactive     2013
```

If there is no record of for example 2015 year in `alumni`, it will still display the other record in `alumni` and 2015 from `member` table. I am trying to display this with `regd` using the following php and mysql statement but it does not work as expected.

Mysql:

```
SELECT m.*, a.* FROM member m 
LEFT JOIN alumni a ON m.regd = a.regd
WHERE m.regd ='1' GROUP BY a.year ORDER BY a.year DESC;
```

PHP:

```
foreach($members as member):
echo $member['regd'].' '.$member['year'].'<br>';
endforeach;
```

The error is, it selects all data from `alumni` table only. Where could I go wrong? Though I did not provide fiddle here, I hope this makes my point clear. please help me.

Comment: `coalesce(member.status, alumni.status)`? If there's no alumni entry, then you get the member entry.

Comment: @Marc B, I am newbie, please can you provide more complete example.

Comment: is is absolutely unclear without fiddle :-)you have no `session` column in data tables you described. and according to th data samples provided it should better be `RIGHT JOIN` since Alumni has more records. And I see no reason to group records untill I see anu duplicates

Comment: @Alex, It must be year, I am mistaken. The reason why I did not use RIGHT JOIN is that member may not be recorded in the alumni table at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `OUTER JOIN` not supported by MySQL.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4796911/4421474

So you should do something like:

```
SELECT res.* FROM (
SELECT 
m.regd, 
m.name, 
COALESCE(m.status, a.status),
m.year,
FROM member m 
LEFT JOIN alumni a 
ON m.regd = a.regd
   AND m.year = a.year
WHERE m.regd ='1' 
UNION
SELECT 
a.regd, 
a.name, 
a.status,
a.year,
FROM member m 
RIGHT JOIN alumni a 
ON m.regd = a.regd
   AND m.year = a.year
WHERE a.regd ='1' 
   AND m.regd IS NULL
) res
ORDER BY res.year DESC
```

Comment: It's working without ORDER BY. The error with ORDER BY is incorrect usage of UNION AND ORDER BY. SO what could be the problem.